# how do i make all checkboxes visible with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, hidden

Hello I'm new to javascript & html and I have a question. In my html is use a lot of checkboxes and I want to make them all invisible when you load the page and when they click a button they all have to become visible. Does anyone know how to do this ? i found the following code bot it doens't look very efficient for me because i use around 35 checkboxes.

js:

```
function showhideid(){
if (document.form.checkbox.checked){   
    document.getElementById("id1").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("id2").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("id3").style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

id1,id2,id3 being the id's I give to my checkboxes.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Naming them IdOne, IdTwo, etc. is a very bad practice. Always use numbers instead, id1, id2, id3, etc.

Comment: I have made the changes. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neatest way to do this is not to change each one. If you have a single action showing and hiding all your checkbox's you can use a css class. So simply have this class on your form on page load.

```
.checkBoxOff input[type="checkbox"]{
    display:none;
}
```

When you want to show your checkbox just remove the class

```
function showhideid(){
if (document.form.checkbox.checked){   
    document.getElementById('yourform').classList.remove('checkBoxOff');
  }
}
```

Comment: if you then reload the page will the .checkBoxOff be remade ?

Comment: If you reload the page the checkbox's will be hidden again

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop for all the IDs

```
for(var i=1;i<=number;i++) {
    document.getElementById("id"+i).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

where `number` is how many checkboxes you have

If you're not sure how the `for` loop works, there are a ton of resources online, such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Answer (score 0):

If all the checkboxes are related, you could package the checkboxes up in another element, such as a DIV. So, you'd have something like this:

```
<div id='allMyCheckboxes'>    
     <input type='checkbox' id='id1'....    
     <input type='checkbox' id='id2'....    
     <input type='checkbox' id='id3'....
    .... 
</div>
```

Then, all your JavaScript would have to do is toggle the visibility of the allMyCheckboxes element.

```
document.getElementById("allMyCheckboxes").style.visibility = "visible";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class for each Checkbox. Say, **class="Checkboxes"** . 
And then in JavaScript type like this.

```
function hideIdClass() {
    document.getElementByClass("Checkboxes").style.visibility= "invisible;"
}

function showIdClass() {
    document.getElementByClass("Checkboxes").style.visibility= "visible";
}
```

And then in your body tag, add this attribute:

```
onload="hideIdClass();"
```

And then in your submit button tag, add this attribute:

```
onclick="showIdClass();"
```